# How to create an ssh tunnel in between 2 computers?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Let's say there are three computers, A, B and C.

Computer A needs to connect to computer C on port 9103.

However it is not able to reach C. But it can reach computer B, which can reach computer C.

I know that this can be done with ssh tunnels. However what makes this complicated is that computer A can't ssh into computer B because of a firewall, but B can ssh into computer A. So a reverse SSH tunnel can be created from B so that A can reach B.

Is there a way that a tunnel can be created on computer B so that computer A can reach computer C by going through computer B?

Comment: `localhost:9103` on C or `eth0:9103`? Can you open any ports on B? Must the connection from A to C be secured by SSH or is connectivity enough?

Answer (score 1):

On B, create a reverse tunnel from A:59103. The endpoint relative to B is C:9103.

```
ssh -R 59103:C:9103 A
```

Change the port number on A from its 59103 to something that suits.

This solution takes your statement that B can reach C at face value. The connection from B to C is not secured with `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be slightly fancy, you can establish an `nc` tunnel on demand instead (if `nc` is installed on B), with something like the following (from host A):

```
$ ssh C -oProxyCommand='ssh -q B nc C 9103'
```

That proxy command means to `ssh` to B and run `nc` connecting to port 9103 on C as tunneling for the ssh connection from A.

If it's something you'd always do, you should put it into`~/.ssh/config` on host A, with the following:

```
host C
    ProxyCommand ssh -q B nc C 9103
```

Then the command line is simply:

```
$ ssh C
```